# Full page size not showing when keypad is up in android

Tags: android, android-keypad

I have 5 `edittext` and 3 `button` in an `xml` fil.

When I focus on the first edittext, the scroll is only going half way but not showing till the end.

I have tried

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and the

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

but when i put this state always visible the problem is i hav tabs in my page that tabs will also jump up when i focus in one edittext
can anybody help!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#517eb9" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Detail_page"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pro_infotwo"
            android:textColor="#d51302"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:text="@string/prodet_id"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/ppid"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip" >

                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:text="@string/keywords"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/pp_key"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:text="@string/prodet_cat1"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/pp_cat"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                        android:ems="10"

                        android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:text="@string/prodet_cat2"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/pp_cat2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                        android:ems="10"

                        android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="1" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:text="@string/vid_url"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/pp_url"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                        android:ems="10"

                        android:paddingLeft="5dip" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Proceed_two"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                     android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                    android:background="#d51302"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:text="@string/proceed"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add your layout XML?

Comment: Don't get the issue. I tried this on my phone and it is working as expected. Can you please clarify (with screenshots if possible) what the exact issue is?

Comment: Also it seems like you are nesting too many LinearLayouts here. You should probably fix this too. See here -> http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html

Comment: anoop the prb is i cant scroll to the last element when the keypad is on

Comment: thanks anoop for the layout issue i will rectify it